# t - sql how to intersect records with 2 columns

Tags: t-sql, relational-division

I have 2 columns

```
Config      Plant
------      -----
ROC         DEP1  
RET         DEP1  
ROC         UAP1
RET         UAP1
SSL         UAP1
ROC         PLP2
RET         PLP2
```

How to get records of `config` which is same for all `plant`s.

In this example result should be

```
ROC
RET
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Config
FROM theTable
GROUP BY Config
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Plant)) FROM theTable)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d925c/1)

Comment: query executed with no results(empty table).Can you please help

Comment: @AsilEris Do you have duplicate rows (Config,Plant)? If so, you need `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Plant)) = ...`